# Помогите пожалуйста с отображением фото на django

Tags: python, django

У меня в бд (postgresql) записаны данные product_name, product_image, product_description, product_price. Изначально в бд я загрузил данные через json-файл и изображения записаны в виде ссылки ("https://basket-05.wb.ru/vol971/part97107/97107829/images/c516x688/1.jpg") и у меня есть страница где авторизованный пользователь может добавить свой продукт со всеми полями включая фото в бд сохраняется как ("static/1644932645_36-fikiwiki-com-p-kartinki.jpg") и это изображение не отображается видно только значок картинки. Вот html код:

```
<ul>
{% for product in accessor %}
    <li>
        <img src="static/{{ product.product_image }}" alt="{{ product.product_name }}" />
        <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.product_name }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

как мне сделать так чтобы и добавленное изображение пользователем отображался корректно?

Comment: Во-первых, если у вас в БД сохраняется static и в шаблоне тоже static, то получается, что у вас два static'а в ссылке. Во-вторых, ваша ссылка является относительной, и то, куда она ведёт, зависит от текущего адреса страницы. В-третьих, в принципе странно, что вы используете static, а не предназначенный для этого media